# Multiple NIC Bonds in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, network-bonding

I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64 on an HP Proliant DL380 G7 (dual CPUs, 24GB RAM, RAID 5 - 300GB). Clean install, nothing else is on the machine. Virtualizing this machine isn't an option or I would already have done that.

I am trying to bond the network connections of the built in 4-port Broadcom NIC with an HP 331T adapter (Broadcom). Both are gigabit and are recognized by Ubuntu (latest firmware has been applied to everything).

I am trying to create two bonds (bond0 and bond1), corresponding to the front-end and back-end network. Each bond has a single connection to each NIC.

I have done an extensive amount of troubleshooting/reading over the past 2 days and have had a little bit of success, but I have run into issues at every step. Most of what I read out there deals with creating a single bond between multiple interfaces. There is virtually no information on creating multiple bonds over multiple interfaces. I am looking for anyone's help/input. It would be greatly appreciated! I figure someone out there has done this in Ubuntu before.

As it stands right now, I have both bonds *mostly* working. If I only wanted a single bond, I would have no problems. The second bond is where the problems start.

- The server hangs at boot trying to start bond1 (which is the 2nd bond). After around 5 minutes, the server finally boots and everything works fine (including bond1)
- Restarting the networking service causes bond1 to become unresponsive. I have to restart the entire machine to get bond1 back. Trying `ifup bond1` results in various issues like `bond1 is already configured/is already up`.

I have also tried `sudo networking service stop && sudo networking service start`, same issue.

Config Files: (have tried virtually every combination of parameters- the following is what got me the furthest)

/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf:

```
alias bond0 bonding options bond0 mode=4 lacp_rate=1 miimon=100 max_bonds=2
alias bond1 bonding options bond1 mode=4 lacp_rate=1 miimon=100 max_bonds=2
```

/etc/network/interfaces (no gateway needed on bond1 - backend):

```
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth4
iface eth4 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 10.100.0.60
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.100.0.1
dns-nameservers 10.100.0.53 10.100.0.54
post-up ifenslave bond0 eth3 eth4
pre-down ifenslave -d bond0 eth3 eth4

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet static
address X.X.X.X
netmask 255.255.255.0
post-up ifenslave bond1 eth0 eth1
pre-down ifenslave -d bond1 eth0 eth1
```

/etc/modules:

```
loop
lp
rtc
bonding
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to verify exit code of the ifenslave of the post-up ?. Documentation says that ifup would fail if exit code is diff from 0